# javaw.exe error and 'Open Object' has encountered a problem

Tags: java, environment, java-home

I have a problem, that none of the Java applications works. A few days ago every application worked and was fine. My computer fell down but I couldn't see any damange on it. Now I wanted to show an application in java and none of the applications worked. I get the error "'Open Object' has encountered a problem". I used my backup to override these applications but they still don't run. Moreover I get javaw.exe error although I set my system variables.

Here u can see the error output.

[image]
[image]

At the end I tried to create a test application and it didn't run too. So I have no idea what I can do. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Okay when I create a new workspace I can include my projects and it works but why ?

Comment: Okay is done. Was my misstake everything works... Just have to reimport the project. How I can delete this question ?

Comment: There should be a delete button at the bottom of the post

Comment: I suggest you leave the question. Others may find themselves in the same predicament.

Comment: Okay I will let it. Anyway It is solved by importing the projects in eclipse again.